# mlr impute seem to take forever & hangs

Tags: r, mlr

I am trying to finish a tutorial problem on a multi-categorical loan prediction using mlr,rpart & randomforest package. I did preprocess the data for NA & missing data yet when i reach the rpart impute part, impute function simply hangs. Any assistance would be great about where i am going wrong.

---

```
# Missing Value Imputation
imp <- impute(train, classes = list(factor = imputeMode(), integer = imputeMean()), dummy.classes = c("integer","factor"), dummy.type = "numeric")
imp1 <- impute(test, classes = list(factor = imputeMode(), integer = imputeMean()), dummy.classes = c("integer","factor"), dummy.type = "numeric")

rpart_num <- imputeLearner(makeLearner("regr.rpart"))
rpart_factor <- imputeLearner(makeLearner("classif.rpart"))
rpart_imp <- impute(train, target = "Loan_Status",
                classes = list(numeric = rpart_num,factor = rpart_factor),
                dummy.classes = c("numeric","factor"),
                dummy.type = "numeric")
```

---

my earlier attempt at rpart impute was

```
rpart_imp <- impute(train, target = "Loan_Status",
                classes = list(numeric = imputeLearner(makeLearner("regr.rpart")),
                factor = imputeLearner(makeLearner("classif.rpart"))),
                dummy.classes = c("numeric","factor"),
                dummy.type = "numeric")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it simply hangs"? How big is the data you're working with?

Comment: The imputeLearner models sends the r console into infinite loop with no response. Dimension of my dataset is :
> dim(LP_full)
[1] 981  21

Comment: Could it just be taking a long time? Please post a full example that allows to reproduce the problem (including all data).